# Is int->double->int guaranteed to be value-preserving?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have an `int`, convert it to a `double`, then convert the `double` back to an `int`, am I guaranteed to get the same value back that I started with?  In other words, given this function:

```
int passThroughDouble(int input)
{
  double d = input;
  return d;
}
```

Am I guaranteed that `passThroughDouble(x) == x` for all `int`s `x`?

Comment: It will depend on the size of int, e.g. for 64 bit ints this will definitely not work. For 32 bit ints it will *probably* work.

Comment: `assert(std::numeric_limits<int>::digits <= std::numeric_limits<double>::digits);` - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits

Comment: @sehe: Surely you mean `static_assert`. :P

Comment: @GManNickG darn. too late to fix :) `static_assert(std::numeric_limits<int>::digits <= std::numeric_limits<double>::digits, "barf");`

Comment: @sehe i think that you should use digits2 here (iirc the digits is base10, and rounds down. so there may be int numbers still not be representable in double).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb are you saying the documentation I linked to is wrong? FWIW I can't see a `digits2` there. There is either `digits` ("_radix_ digits") or `digits10`. Made sense to me

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I'm just happy I'm not the only one with bad memory for futile details. I look it up everytime. Cheers

Comment: of course any compiler worthy of the name will optimize out the fiddling about with the double and simply return input directly. Or maybe not - if the compiler writer knows that the result is not guaranteed :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No it isn't. The standard says nothing about the relative sizes of `int` and `double`.

If `int` is a 64-bit integer and `double` is the standard IEEE double-precision, then it will already fail for numbers bigger than `2^53`.

---

That said, `int` is still 32-bit on the majority of environments today. So it will still hold in many cases.

Comment: in what system does int have 64 bit though? windows and linux both have it at 32bit.

Comment: I dont think C says IEEE double precision. It just says double precision; meaning twice the precision of float. So 64 bit int might fit in double exactly (clearly not guaranteed tho)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I've heard of some linux distribution having 64-bit `int`s. But that was second-hand info I got from the lounge.

Comment: @pm100: I don't think C says a `double` has twice the precision of float either, they could be the same size.  However, Mysticial's post is right.  "if... double is the standard IEEE double-precision..."

Comment: Indeed, I've seen one compiler (LCC?) that implemented both `float` and `double` using double-precision.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: The question specifically asks if it's "guaranteed". "I couldn't find a system where it doesn't work" is not a guarantee.

Comment: @david it sounds as though you think that i said that it is guaranteed.

Answer (score 12):

If we restrict consideration to the "traditional" IEEE-754-style representation of floating-point types, then you can expect this conversion to be value-preserving if and only if the mantissa of the type `double` has as many bits as there are non-sign bits in type `int`.

Mantissa of a classic IEEE-754 `double` type is 53-bit wide (including the "implied" leading bit), which means that you can represent integers in `[-2^53, +2^53]` range precisely. Everything out of this range will generally lose precision.

So, it all depends on how wide your `int` is compared to your `double`. The answer depends on the specific platform. With 32-bit `int` and IEEE-754 `double` the equality should hold.

Comment: Digital audio systems depend on integer to floating-point to integer conversions to work, or 'the world would stop spinning'. As someone who had to delve into the theory of the topic and to conduct some practical experiments, I can only say that this is the right answer.